# Unable to populate JSON Data in ExtJS grid (4.2.1) in Grails 2.1

Tags: json, grails, extjs

The JSON data is in Correct Format ! yet i am unable to bind the JSON data with the Grid . I dont even get an Empty Grid ! The problem lies with my extjs code,I am a new to Extjs! i am using 4.2.1

I am Trying to Render the Grid in the upload.gsp div by using
     `renderTo: 'csvGrid'` in the extjs Panel .

It simply Renders the JSON data but not inside the grid ! Please help !

```
     Grails Contoller Actions  Contoller Code 

        def index() {

                render (view:"upload")
            }


            def upload() {

                def uploadedCSVFile = request.getFile('file')
        //      def csvMap = [:]
        //      def  listOfCsvMap = []

                def   materialCode
                def   serialNumber
                def   label

                String  [] row ;
                char separator = ';';
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(uploadedCSVFile.getInputStream()),separator);




                String [] header = reader.readNext()
                //  String [] temp;
                if (header[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Material_Code") && header[1].equalsIgnoreCase("Serial_Number") && header[2].equalsIgnoreCase("#Labels") )
                {

                    List <String []> fileData = reader.readAll()
                    Iterator<String[]> rowIterator =     fileData.iterator()



                    def  listOfCsvMap = []

                        while (rowIterator.hasNext())

                    {



                        def csvMap = [:]

                        row =  rowIterator.next()

                        materialCode = row.collect().get(0)
                        serialNumber = row.collect().get(1)
                        label    = row.collect().get(2)

                        csvMap.put('Material_Code', materialCode)
                        csvMap.put('Serial_Number', serialNumber)
                        csvMap.put('Labels', label)
                        listOfCsvMap.add(csvMap)


                    }



                render([items:listOfCsvMap] as JSON)


         upload.gsp 

        <body>
          <div class="body">

          <g:uploadForm action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload"/>
        </g:uploadForm>

         <g:javascript src="grid.js" />

         <div id="csvGrid"> </div>


        and in the grid.js 


        var store1;
        Ext.onReady(function() {
                 store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                storeId: 'myStore1',
                pageSize: 20,
                proxy: {
                     type: 'ajax',
                     url:'upload',
                      reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'items'

                    }

                },
                fields: ['Material_Code','Serial_Number','Labels']

            }); 
            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                store: store1,
                stateful: false,
                layout:'fit',
                enableColumnMove: true,
                enableColumnResize:true,  
                emptyText:'<b style="font-size:14px;color: #F49000;">'+'Please fill all the mandatory fields!!!'+'</b>',

                columns: [
                    {
                        text     : 'Material Code',
                        width:175,
                        sortable : true,
                        dataIndex: 'Material_Code',
                     },
                     {
                         text     : 'Serial Number',
                         width :275,
                         sortable : true,
                         dataIndex: 'Serial_Number'
                     },
                     {
                         text     : '#Labels',
                         width :275,
                         sortable : true,
                         dataIndex: 'Labels'
                     }

                ],
                bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
                store: store1,
                    pageSize: 20,
                    displayInfo: true,
                    displayMsg: 'Displaying rows {0} - {1} of {2}',
                    emptyMsg: "No rows to display"

                }),
                height: 350,
                width: 850,
                renderTo: 'csvGrid',
                viewConfig: {
                    stripeRows: true,
                    enableTextSelection:true
                }
            });
            store1.reload();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that is causing the issue directly is this :

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The action is `upload`, which is the url that returns the JSON.

A solution would be to create a separate page, define it as action and load the JavaScript on that page.

Alternatively, instead of submitting the form you can send the values as parameters when you load the store (pass them in the options object of `store1.load({params: {...}})`. In this case it would be a better design to create the whole page with extjs, including the form.

There are other problems with the code, like you have `store1.reload();`, but you never called `load()` before.

Comment: Thanks a lot !Lorenz!  I managed to achieve what i wanted to, by doing what you had suggested and a little help from Sencha documentation !